# data.table: Different result whether assignment is chained or within same square bracket as subsetting

Tags: r, data.table, assign, chaining

In the working example below, we see that the operations `dt[i, j]` and `dt[i][,j]` are not equivalent in their output. I would have assumed that chaining did not make a difference, but clearly it does. What is happening under the hood and why is this intended behavior?

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

  # Order A
dates <- as.Date(c("2022-08-18", "2022-10-20"))
db <- data.frame(id = 1:2, d = dates)
dt <- data.table(db)

dt[, month := months(dates)]
print(dt) # month is character

dt[id == 1][, month := lubridate::month(d)]
print(dt) # month remains character

dt[id == 1, month := lubridate::month(d)]
print(dt) # month is numeric



  # Order B
dates <- as.Date(c("2022-08-18", "2022-10-20"))
db <- data.frame(id = 1:2, d = dates)
dt <- data.table(db)

dt[, month := months(dates)]
print(dt) # month is character

dt[id == 1, month := lubridate::month(d)]
print(dt) # month is numeric

dt[id == 1][, month := lubridate::month(d)]
print(dt) # month remains numeric
```

Comment: try `dt[id == 1][, month := lubridate::month(d)][]` : chaining creates a subsetted dataset which isn't anymore linked by reference to the original dataset, hence the difference you observe.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I am afraid I don't follow the reasoning. If I do `dt2 <- dt[id==1]` and then `dt2[,month := lubridate::month(d)]`, how is this different from chaining?  I am still operating on a subsetted dataset but here there is no issue referencing the variable name 'd'. I also see your proposal returns the desired behavior, but what does chaining with an empty bracket fix?

Comment: Empty bracket is to print the content of the subsetted data set (with only id==1) : it is modified as expected. The initial dataset with all rows isn't modified. The other syntax `dt[id == 1, month := lubridate::month(d)]` modifies the original dataset.

Comment: Now I see, my expected behavior would require to write `dt[id == 1] <- dt[id == 1][, month := lubridate::month(d)]` then. I see also that this expected behavior is what people do by using the `magrittr` pipe `%>%` as in `dt[id ==1] %>% .[, month := lubridate::month(d)]` and that is not equivalent to chaining. If you write a short answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:=` modifies the input object by reference, see [reference semantics](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

You can observe this using `tracemem()`:

```
tracemem(dt)
#[1] "<000001CEC9999820>"
tracemem(dt[, month := months(dates)])
#[1] "<000001CEC9999820>"
# Same address
```

However, in `dt[id == 1][, month := lubridate::month(d)]`, the input object is `dt[id == 1]`, a subset of `dt` that has another memory address :

```
tracemem(dt[id == 1])
[1] "<000001CEC939EBB0>"
# different than dt's address ; changes to this object by reference don't modify dt
```